# Assist me to understand the ethtool output

Tags: ubuntu, networking

We have two servers that connect to a third party platform. One server has constant communication issues, the other does not.

I validated using the 'route' command that both servers use 'eth0'

When I do 'ethtool eth0' on the server that has NO connectivity problems I get this:

```
   Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ Backplane ]
        Supported link modes:   100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  100000baseKR4/Full
                                100000baseSR4/Full
                                100000baseCR4/Full
                                100000baseLR4_ER4/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Port: Direct Attach Copper
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Current message level: 0x000000f7 (247)
                               drv probe link ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
        Link detected: yes
```

When I check the server that has BAD connectivity problems I see a lot different:

```
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [  ]
        Supported link modes:   Not reported
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 50000Mb/s
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Port: None
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Current message level: 0x000000f7 (247)
                               drv probe link ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
        Link detected: yes
```

These servers are both Ubuntu 22.04 servers hosted on Azure

Where does this configuration come from? How can I change the one to be like the other?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
ip -s link show eth0
```

It might be due to some missing driver so try comparing the output of `lsmod` on both servers.